# Method that includes fetch wont change the value of an object

Tags: vuejs2

A method that contains a fetch API call, wont update the user object

I have a login component witch is only active if the object user is null.
The login button activates the method  witch activates a fetch with a put request, and gets data back from my back-end. The API call works and gets the wanted data, but when i try to update my object it stays null, so my login component wont disappear.

this is the login component that needs to disappear when the object user updates

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="user === null">
    <Login class="login" v-on:check-user="checkUser"/>
    </div>



  </div>
</template>
```

This is where i initialize the user object and the method that is suppose to update the said object.
the alert returns the whole object as it should be but the login component isn't disappearing

```
 data(){
    return{
      user: null,
      coupons:[],
      shops:[],
    }
  },
  methods:{
    checkUser(mak){
      alert(this.user);
      fetch("http://localhost:8080/kupom/kupoman/user", {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(mak)
        })
            .then(response=> {
            return response.json();


          })
          .then(data=>{
            this.user=data;
            alert(JSON.stringify(this.user));
          });
      },
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: no,it just doesnt update...i am reading on the internet it has something to do with fetch being an asynchrone method....what does it mean in regards to my code?

Comment: Try using `async/await`. More on this [here](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Comment: So it would look something like `async checkUser(mak)` and 
`let results = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/kupom/kupoman/user", {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(mak)
        })`. So results would be the Promise returned from `fetch`.

Comment: and can i just do user=await... instead of results=await?

Comment: That should work too. I would also wrap it in a `try/catch` block in case `fetch` returns any rejects.

Comment: Although, what you did should work too...take a look at the HelloWorld component in this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-g24gh) (it's under the components folder)

Comment: yes, i know...i tried the await thing...didnt work, and fetch doesnt work when being under await...dont know what to do..

Comment: you mean in my original code?If so, it outputs the full set of data that i need, the api fetch worked perfectly

Comment: Within the first `div`, put this in and see if its true or false before and after the fetch: `{{ user === null }}`

Comment: it says true...

Comment: That's strange...[this](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-h8dpe)(within the HelloWorld component) is similar to your code. Change the values where needed and see if it works on your side because it seems to be working in the example.

Comment: it finally works...i wanted to try to do the fetch method in the component itself, and used  async/await and emited the data to the app.vue...thank you very much for all your help !